# How to process messages in avro format from Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

I am trying to implement below kafka-console-consumer command(works well & output the intended json data) functionality in the form of program using spark streaming.

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper host.xxxx.com:2181,host.xxxx.com:2181 --topic mytopic --formatter CustomAvroMessageFormatter --property "formatter-schema-file= schema.txt" > /var/tmp/myfile.json&
```

I am able to read message from above topic using spark streaming programatically as below scala code which works well:

```
object ConsumeTest {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "ConsumeKafkaMsg")
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))

  //To read from server
  val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "brokername:9092")
  val topics = List("mytopic").toSet

  val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[
   String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics).map(_._2)

  lines.print()

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

However above program read message in binary format something similar to below:

```
��Cߣ�ߕ'윺~�_,��M˶/��Ѯ!�Vcusomtername client
2X3XXXXXX-sasadsad-4673-212c-dsdsadsad
value
,"question"logName
successstԇ���V
```

against above command use custom avro formatter to convert binary format to json format using avro schema. I am unable to find out how to use command equivalent avro message formatter in my above program which is important to achieve.

Below is the probable avro schema(schema.txt) for reference(actually v complex what is available to process):

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "namespace" : "mynamespace",
  "name" : "myname",
  "fields" : [{
    "name":"field1",
    "type":{
      "type":"record",
      "name":"Eventfield1",
      "fields":[{.....}]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Please help to implement the same.

Answer (score -1):

You've got two choices (and both require fairly intense coding which is OK, isn't it? :)).

1. Write your own custom Kafka [Deserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) and use it where you use `StringDecoder` in your example.
2. After you loaded a dataset (for a batch) convert it using `foreach` operator or use `map` transformation that applies the conversion as part of the pipeline.

You could also consider using [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) library.